How can I implement IAM in my custom Cloud Run service on GCP?
The Cloud Run service I am working on was implemented requiring authentication (IAM managed).
The service should now be extended to handle GitHub events as a GitHub App. As I understand this means the service needs to be publicly accessible now.
We opted to add middleware which protects the legacy routes and leave the GitHub routes open, since GitHub has its own security mechanic for calling back to GitHub.
There is some logic now to check the iss and hd claims to have certain values to make sure the ID token is valid.
Now I just realized though, that this not enough. I also want to check that the identity has permissions to invoke the Cloud Run service.
How would I do that? I couldn't find any API in that regard.
EDIT: Or is there perhaps a way to require authentication and still be able to call the Cloud Run from a GitHub App?

My recommendation is to create a separate service that is publicly accessible, which handles GitHub events.
Then you fully isolate a service that is publicly accessible and can give that service account minimum permissions it needs.
